# Use webpack and babel to convert ES6 to ES5 file javascript but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, babel-loader

I use webpack and babel to convert ES6 to ES5 file javascript but it doesn't work. File code javascript contains many functions.

This is file webpack.config.cjs:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader', // Use babel-loader for transpilation
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I use original file, it works normally, but when I use minified file after use webpack, it return error with "handleChange is not function"...
What do I need to do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: The posted code and the error seem to have little to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

My code in `webpack.config.js` (this code should be added to `rules` array):

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
      },
    },
  },
```

My code in `package.json`:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
```

Does it useful for you? Looks like presets are lacks in your code.

`babel.config.json` (this file should be created near of webpack.config.js)

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```